# C++ save in file and plot data eventually

Tags: c++, graphics

I have written a program in C++ where I finally got two arrays of values.

Now I want to save them and plot them with an external program(each array by itself).

Could anybody give me a code-reference how to save these arrays in a file and which (for example GNU) program could plot them?

Does nobody know how to save these arrays appropriately in a file?

Comment: What format do you want to save them in? What data is contained in the array (int, float, etc.)?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I want the format that can be understood by Octave. All double

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it is write them to a text file and haul them into GNU Octave (MATLAB clone).

```
a = [
1,
2,
3,
4,
5
];
b = [
2,
4,
6,
8,
10
];
plot(a);
plot(b);
```

Comment: and how do I save these in a text-file? what is the right command to do this, so that Octave can read them?

Comment: To write to a text file, you use fprintf().  C/C++ 100 (as in not even 101-level).  You are going to have to do some reading on Octave for the rest.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is open a file for writing and write the data to it. Since you haven't provided much information about how you are managing the array or what type of data it contains it's hard to provide anything other than a basic example.

The code below opens a file for writing and writes out the contents of an array. It writes the data in a basic format that should be usable by Octave. You can expand on the example to better suit your exact needs.

```
#include <fstream>

void savedata(const std::string& filename, const double* data, size_t size)
{
    std::fstream out(filename);
    out << "a = [" << std::endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        out << data[i] << ((i + 1 < size) ? "," : "") << std::endl;
    }
    out << "];" << std::endl;
    out << "plot(a);" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    double data[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

    savedata("output.txt", data, 5);
}
```

This results in the following output

> a = [
>   0,
>   1,
>   2,
>   3,
>   4
>   ];
>   plot(a);

Comment: I've updated the example to include properly generating a comma after each entry so make sure you take that into account when you start fiddling with it

Comment: *Please*, this is the [C++] Tag. Do we *really* want to give answers with `const double* data, size_t size` when the question is so general? How 'bout working with `std::vector` for a change? :-) (Oh, and I still upvoted because it's a nice and helpful answer.)

Comment: Yes using `std::vector` would certainly be a much better and safer choice however the OP is using arrays. Rather than introduce confusion (they don't seem to even be familiar with streams) or cause them to try changing their existing codebase I chose to use plain old arrays. **But** I should have at least suggested switching to `std::vector` ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend gnuplot. That's what I use.

It can get simple files with one value per line (or 2 values per line, separated by space, for X,Y plotting)

Once you run gnuplot, just execute the command

```
plot 'filename' w l
```

and it will plot the data in filename with lines.

**Edit**

copied the code from another answer and converted it to gnuplot format:

```
#include <fstream>

void savedata(const std::string& filename, const double* data, size_t size)
{
    std::fstream out(filename);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        out << data[i] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    double data[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

    savedata("output.txt", data, 5);
}
```

Then from the shell run gnuplot and in gnuplot the command

```
plot "output.txt" w l
```

That's it!

Comment: I'll have to look into this.  I'm used to hauling stuff into Octave and massaging it there before I plot it.  (Octave actually uses Gnuplot to plot.)